# Taking the tuple formation (dictionary) as input and outputting it especially the pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, indexing

These entries:

```
{'Ali' :[('xyz' ,1), ('who' ,2),('kml' ,1)],
'Veli' : [('xyz' ,4)],
'Hasan' : [('xyz' ,2),('dep' ,7)]}
```

What pandas `dataframe` code can be written to get this output:

```
person  Ali  Veli  Hasan
GUID                    
xyz     1.0   4.0    2.0
who     2.0   NaN    NaN
kml     1.0   NaN    NaN
dep     NaN   NaN    7.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `DataFrame` constructor with convert list of tuples to dictionaries:

```
d = {'Ali' :[('xyz' ,1),('who' ,2),('kml' ,1)],
     'Veli' : [('xyz' ,4)], 
     'Hasan' : [('xyz' ,2),('dep' ,7)]}

df = pd.DataFrame({k: dict(v) for k, v in d.items()})
print (df)
     Ali  Veli  Hasan
xyz  1.0   4.0    2.0
who  2.0   NaN    NaN
kml  1.0   NaN    NaN
dep  NaN   NaN    7.0
```

If need also index and columns names add [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df = df.rename_axis(index='GUID', columns='person')
print (df)
person  Ali  Veli  Hasan
GUID                    
xyz     1.0   4.0    2.0
who     2.0   NaN    NaN
kml     1.0   NaN    NaN
dep     NaN   NaN    7.0
```

Comment: Thanks for your concern :D 
i have a question;